# PushBot Push Notification:Persistent Notification in Notification Center

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, xcode5

I'm Using PushBots to implement push notifiaction in my iOS application.When I select one of the notification from the Notification Center all my notification gets removed from the same.Is there any way to persist the notification in the Notification Center Or remove only the selected notification from the same.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Are you resetting the badge count in your app?

Comment: yes we are decrementing the badgecount by one.

Comment: After reducing badge count by one are you also decreasing the count in pushBot server?
// Decrease Badge count by 1
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber -1];
// Decrease badge count on the server
[[Pushbots getInstance] decreaseBadgeCountBy:@"1"];

Comment: yes,we are doing both